# css for nested divs and classes

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to make display:none for class generic_layout_container layout_core_menu_logo i.e at 11th line but it is not happening somehow. can anybody help 
here is my css to get desired result

```
#global_page_user-profile-index #global_header .generic_layout_container layout_main .generic_layout_container layout_core_menu_logo {
  display:none;
}
```

i think tht the codes are wrong plz correct me. Thanks

Comment: Screenshots of code are highly discouraged. It makes it extremely difficult to replicate, suggest revisions, etc. Please create a simple example instead.

Comment: I think you meant to use `#global_page_user-profile-index #global_header .generic_layout_container.layout_main .generic_layout_container.layout_core_menu_logo { display: none; }`

Comment: There's absolutely no need to nest multiple ID since clearly ID is a unique selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the css you provided is the actual css you're using the problem is the following:

Current CSS:

```
#global_page_user-profile-index #global_header .generic_layout_container layout_main .generic_layout_container layout_core_menu_logo {
    display:none;
}
```

Fixed CSS:

```
#global_page_user-profile-index #global_header .generic_layout_container.layout_main .generic_layout_container.layout_core_menu_logo {
    display:none;
}
```

Also next time just provide code instead of screenshots.

You added a couple of extra spaces so the css takes it as an element.

Also by reading @Roko C. Buljan's comment, yes.

If you give an ID to an element you could directly use `display: none` on it, since id's should be unique.

Comment: There's usually no need to nest multiple ID descendants and bloat CSS unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

If both classes are on the same element you need to remove the space in between:

```
.generic_layout_container.layout_core_menu_log {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.generic_layout_container layout_main .generic_layout_container layout_core_menu_logo

You have an empty space between: .generic_layout_container layout_main, and also: .generic_layout_container layout_core_menu_logo

You need to concatenate the classes by replacing the space with a period.